# Re-entry permit while on Extension of Stay in Thailand?

Tags: visa, thailand

**Am I eligible for Re-entry permit** if my stay in Thailand is based on *Extension of Stay*, and my visa has been expired a long ago?
As far as I understand, **re-entry** permit can be issued only during the validity of visa itself, not based on Extension of Stay.

---

Long story.
My understanding is that visa is a permission to *enter* the country. Usually, it is valid for 90 days only, single entry (ED type).
Permit to *stay* is the legal validation of living in the country.
An ED-type visa holder needs to apply for Extension of Stay each 90 days **during the entire course of study** (up to 3 or 5 years, depending on the license granted to a particular school).
Hence, just after the 1st extension, your legal stay exceeds the term of visa validity (90 days).
On the other hand, re-entry is logically tied with visa itself (by increasing the number of **entries** to the country), not based on the extension of **stay**.

Considering the above, is it possible to issue the *Re-entry permit* after the visa has been expired?

---

**Edit**: a little math to clarify. All dates are rough since all durations are 90 days (≠ 3 months).

- On `Jan/01` I obtain the ED visa;
- Visa is valid to enter the country up to `Apr/01`, single entry;
- On `Feb/10` I enter the country;
- At the airport, I get stamp saying that my *stay* is valid up to `May/10 (= Feb/10 + 90 days)`;
- Assume that on `March/15` I want to temporarily leave. I apply in the Immigration office to get Re-entry permit which is valid to enter back the country up to `Apr/01` (the date of visa validity), no problem;
- On `May/10` I apply to the Immigration office to extend my stay up to `Aug/10 (= May/10 + 90 days)`;
- Assume that on `July/15` I want to temporarily exit the country and return back on `July/20`;

At this moment, **visa** is expired (back on `April/01`). I doubt that re-entry has no sense when visa is expired.

Comment: Any chance you could [edit] to clarify your question a bit? Most longer-term visas assume that you will leave and re-enter the country. Some countries require an additional 're-entry visa' (often at an additional fee) to come back using the same visa you had when you left. Others don't require one. So if you can't re-enter the country on your current visa, chances are you need to have a re-entry permit, and it's probably able to be gotten with your current visa. It may help to clarify what your problem is, and what you've already found out about your situation to get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: The expiry date of the visa is not relevant after you have used it to enter Thailand (assuming a single-entry visa). The only important date is the "leave by" date they stamp in your passport when you enter. If you get a re-entry permit, you can use it to re-enter until the last day of your stay.

Comment: Also - note (and this caught me out the first time I got a re-entry permit) that you must write the number of the re-entry permit on the arrival card when you arrive, not the original visa number! This is because the visa is now used, and the re-entry permit is now your permission to enter the country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A re-entry permit only allows you to exit Thailand and re-enter. It does not grant you any additional time for your current stay. So if you have a 90-day entry from a single-entry visa, you can get a re-entry permit to allow you to leave and come back, but when you come back the "exit by" date stamped in your passport will be the same as the one from the previous entry.

If you were employed (and therefore had an extension of stay based on having a work permit), your company would probably get you a 'multiple' re-entry permit when doing the extension, to allow you to leave and come back as often as necessary during the year that you are working with them. All my employers have done this (past and present), and from memory it costs 3,800 Baht for the 'multiple' re-entry permit.

Also, to clarify: a visa is the permission to enter - and when you do enter you get an entry stamp with a "leave by" date. If you get a re-entry permit, you can exit and then re-enter at any time up to the "leave by" date. The validity of the visa is irrelevant because you already used it (and it has a red "USED" stamp on it).

Comment: So my biggest misunderstanding was that the re-entry is tied to visa validity period, however it is not. Thanks a lot!